# Me sale error 400 con el api de instabot en python

Tags: python, instagram

Actualmente quiero generar un bot para instagram el cual debe de seguir a las personas de otra cuenta de forma automática pero me sale un error:

Código python:

```
# importar la clase a utilizar
from instabot import Bot
# crear el nuevo objeto
mi_bot = Bot()
mi_bot.login(username='xxxxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxxx')
mi_bot.follow_followers('xxxxxxxx')
```

Lo ejecuto en el cmd de la siguiente forma.

```
python main.py
```

y el error que sale es el siguiente:

```
2020-02-20 17:23:10,742 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (bot) - INFO - Instabot version: 0.107.0 Started
2020-02-20 17:23:10,773 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api_login) - INFO - PRE-LOGIN FLOW!... 
2020-02-20 17:23:22,801 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - ERROR - Request returns 400 error!
2020-02-20 17:23:22,801 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - INFO - Instagram's error message: challenge_required
2020-02-20 17:23:22,801 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - INFO - Error type: checkpoint_challenge_required
2020-02-20 17:23:22,801 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - INFO - Checkpoint challenge required...
2020-02-20 17:23:22,816 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (bot_follow) - INFO - Follow followers of: xxxxxxxxxxxx
2020-02-20 17:23:22,816 - instabot version: 0.107.0 (api) - CRITICAL - Not logged in!
```

La versión de python que uso es la 3.8.1, que por lo que tengo entendido es la mas reciente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera vez que inicies sesión, debe de ser así:

```
bot.login(ask_for_code=True)
```

Solo la primera vez.